# Android menu item separetor (menu item in different line)

Tags: android, menu

How can i define each menu item in different line?
Right now if I'm adding 4 items they will get the form of 2X2. Is there a way to add them differently? Like 1 item and 3 below it? or 1X4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you put them in different groups it will try to keep them together depending on what kind of space is available.

Comment: There is no way to control the layout like you specified. Grouping is the most control you have over a menu layout

Answer (score 1):

You can't do 1x3 or 1x4 with this, but you can also try changing the order of items (if you have that flexibility) to control which menu items get grouped together. Having 3 items puts 1 item on top, and 2 items on the bottom.